# What is an Operator Matrix for the operation which happens in the reverse direction?

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, matrix-calculus, random-matrices

I have a model of an operation which happens in one direction. For example assume a rotation matrix R. transpose of R would mean rotation in reverse direction. Am I correct with the physical inter pretation of transpose of a matrix ?
If so what if the forward operator matrix A is complex. How can I denote the reverse operator? Is it A transpose or conj(Atranspose) ?

Comment: I think what you want is the inverse of the matrix. For a rotation the transpose happens to be the inverse. For other operations determined by a matrix that may not be the case.

Comment: Suppose I have a forward scattering of light denoted by A. Then back ward scattering through the same medium would it  be inverse of A or A transpose or conj(Atranspose). I am confused.

Comment: You want the inverse of $A$.